# How to measure time when being logged in

Tags: java

I want to implement a project where I check system timings whenever I am logged in.
If I enter the office and log in my system the I should get the time and also when I go for a break I just lock my PC and go so at that time time should stop and again when I login it should start.

Basically it should show me the total time I was logged in my computer/PC.

Comment: And you want to do that in Java?!

Comment: Start with `System.currentTimeMillis()`, or http://www.dice.com.

Comment: But TBH, I don't feel Java is well suited for this purpose. I recommend switching over to a language such as C# which gives you access to system level api.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` (or `System.nanoTime()`) for the start and the end, and then calculate the difference.

This will give you the time when you start / close Java. Linking this to system startup / system shutdown can be done by launching the application on startup. But that depends on the OS.

Comment: This may be the way to measure time but how can you detect machine logon events in Java?

Answer (score 0):

In java you can obtain the time by several ways. Two of them are :

- instanciate a new Date object :
  Date myDate = new Date() ;
- using :
  System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.I am newbie to Java.what should i write in batch file? I have created a java class file which outputs the current time so what i need to write in batch file and how to corelate? PLease answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should think of using a software dedicated to that instead of implementing this in Java.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is this:

1. Create a Java application that can
   log the time somewhere, using the
   `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `new
   Date()` approach.
2. Create a scheduled task in windows
   that runs each time the user locks,
   unlocks, logs on and logs off the
   system. This scheduled task should
   run your application. It should be
   as simple as calling a batch file
   which in turn invokes your Java
   application.
3. The application should use all the
   times captured to calculate the
   effective time.

Comment: While that should work, using C or C++ that can access the system APIs (if .NET has adequate libs that also works, but no idea about that) sounds like a lot less work, especially considering that the actual logic (start/stop timer) is pretty trivial.

Comment: I second that. In fact, that's exactly what I have updated in the main question's comments section.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.I am newbie to Java.what should i write in batch file? I have created a java class file which outputs the current time so what i need to write in batch file and how to corelate? PLease answer.

Comment: If your class file name is `MeasureTime.class` then write in the batchfile `java MeasureTime` and execute the `.bat` file. The batch file should be in the same directory as the `.class` file else if in a different directory change the directory using `cd` command before runing the `.class` file.